# Ag-grid row drag property is not working in angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

-> [rowDragManaged]="true" this property is not working in my ag-grid component

-> Check the image one from the backend team I got rowdrag true property in columnDefs

->In image 2 in the UI also it is applied

->But in image 3 when I add [rowDragManaged]="true" in my HTML ag-grid component it is disappearing from the UI how to fix it and make row drag work properly here

[image: Image1], [image: Image2],  [image: Image3]

```
 <div @fadeIn>
            <ag-grid-angular
              style="width: 100%; height: calc(94vh - 150px);"
              class="ag-theme-balham"
              [rowData]="agGridOptions?.results"
              [columnDefs]="agGridOptions?.columnDefs"
              [rowDragManaged]="true"
              [animateRows]="animateRows"
              [rowGroupPanelShow]="'always'"
              [floatingFilter]="agGridOptions?.floatingFilter"
              [paginationAutoPageSize]="paginationAutoPageSize"
              [paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize"
              [pagination]="pagination"
              (modelUpdated)="onDataRendered($event)"
              (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event?.data)"
              (rowSelected)="onRowSelected($event)">
            </ag-grid-angular>
          </div>
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question please? I don't think it is very clear at the moment. What images are you referring to in what parts of your text?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `[pagination]="false"` will work.

Comment: Please add WHY this works, so that other users with the same problem can understand and learn from this too.